# Is there a diagram based language for modelling security?

Tags: account-security

A lot of us will be familiar with UML for software engineering. Its uses are plentiful.

Is there such a thing as a set of conventionally used diagrams for modelling any security scenario (speaking as a complete beginner to the field of security).

For example, if I wanted to sketch out all the different ways a client's password database could be breached, given that she has situations like the file being stored in the cloud, 2FA with a physical key, application on her phone, etc.

The idea would be to have a clear, pictographical overview of the situation, and ideally be able to easily see flaws or how to best optimise the security given the person's lifestyle.

Answer (score 1):

I have not (yet) found such (markup) language for modelling.

This was the closest I found, but it's not really suitable:
[Secure Tropos](https://www.brighton.ac.uk/csius/what-we-do/research-projects/secure-tropos.aspx)

*"Secure Tropos is a security-aware software systems development methodology"*